# A dependency to an entry point is not allowed in multiple page app with react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, entry-point

I carefully searched the same problem that I faced but didn't find anything helpful.

**webpack 1.13.1. Mac OS X El Capitan last version.**

## What I am trying to accomplish

I want to create a webpack build to develop multiple page apps.

I want to see the structure like this:
**source**

```
/source/page1/page1.css
/source/page1/page1.js
/source/page1/page1.html
```

**public**

```
/public/page1/page1.css
/public/page1/page1.js
/public/page1/page1.html
```

## Current build

This is what I've done.
https://gist.github.com/lavezzi1/9cc0e58cd7d2b8f2470e703022a41db7

I tested it with **vue.js** and it works perfect. But now I want to get it works with **react.js** as well. 
In dev move everything works just fine but when I ran task for prod build I got this error:

> ERROR in ./source/pages/index.js
>   Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed

What I did. This is my page folder:
[image: screen shot 2016-08-21 at 00 52 57]

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So what am I doing wrong? I am newbie in react.js, maybe I don't understand something.

In vue.js I just create files:

```
index.html
index.css
index.vue
index.js
```

And everything works as expected.

I really really hope you guys help me.

Comment: why don't you just indicate the js file as entry point and import the css in that entry file.  For multiple js entry file you can use the code splitting feature of webpack. https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: How to indicate that this file is an entry point?

Comment: i have indicated that as an answer. if it is helpful don't forget to mark it as accepted as it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just indicate the js file as entry point and import the css in that entry file. For multiple js entry file you can use the code splitting feature of webpack.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

and in your webpack.config.js file you can define entry file like the following.

```
entry: { 
    lite: "./lite.js", pro: "./pro.js",
},
output: { filename: "dist/[name].js" },
```

Comment: I have 200 entry points and its grow. I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: you can implement logic in js to read all the entry file in a folder and include that.